# Incrementing Date - SQL(Snowflake)

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want  to Increment/Decrement the Year , Day , Month by pulling in the Current Date in Snowflake in a single query ?
For e.g.

Suppose Current System Date - 04082021 I want to make it 05092022. I have tried the dateadd function but I suppose it allows only one part i.e. either year or month or day to be incremented at once.

Is it Possible ? If Not, What are the other alternatives ?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use`DATEADD` function, here is the code:

```
SELECT DATEADD(YEAR,+1,DATEADD(MONTH,+1,DATEADD(DAY,+1,CURRENT_DATE())));
```

returns `2022-09-05` from `2021-08-04`

If you want to keep your format, Please use following code

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(DATEADD(YEAR,+1,DATEADD(MONTH,+1,DATEADD(DAY,+1,CURRENT_DATE()))),'DDMMYYYY');
```

Comment: It does add the date but I want  to preserve the format

Comment: If you want to keep your format, Please use following code
SELECT TO_CHAR(DATEADD(YEAR,+1,DATEADD(MONTH,+1,DATEADD(DAY,+1,CURRENT_DATE()))),'DDMMYYYY');

Comment: Please use format code for better visibility

Answer (score 1):

I would do the arithmetic in thee parts:

```
select current_date + interval '1 year' + interval '1 month' + interval '1 day'
```

You can also use:

```
select current_date + interval '1 year, 1 month, 1 day'
```

Comment: It Increments the Value fine but there are two issues .

1. The format has to be without the the hyphen and this is unidirectional that is either I can increment value or decrement  the value but not both.